# Delete an unassigned member in list

Tags: prolog

i write a code , to get some specific output (2 List) , and it's work , and give me what i need , but there are unassigned element in the two list ,as shown below ,so my question is : how to delete thess unassigned elements .

```
 Courses = [_G1619, linear, _G1607, physics2, physics1, calculas1|_G1590],
Marks = [_G1622, 78, _G1610, 90, 80, 78|_G1593]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you include in your tags which prolog interpreter you are using (*e.g.,* GNU Prolog, SWI Prolog, etc).

Comment: What you really want is to build your list without these unwanted elements in the first place.  Find the place in your code where these elements are generated (presumably because some course is not applicable to a student), and "short-circuit" the result-list there (i.e. unify the tail of the list-so-far with the head of the list-still-to-build).  You also need to check your termination rule: it should generate empty list(s).  This will in turn make your final lists properly terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog there are some list processing utilities like [exclude](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=exclude/3)/3, that allow to specify a predicate to be used on each element. [var](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=var/1)/1 seems appropriate. For instance

```
2 ?- exclude(var,[1,A,B,2,3|L],R).
L = [],
R = [1, 2, 3] ;
...
```

(note: place a cut after the call to get rid of nondeterminism).

I was surprised to find it also removed the unbounded tail - I thought it would require a proper list. Then it should fit your request.